# Multiple GridFS on a Mongo Database and Multiple Files

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs, nosql

I am wondering it is possible to have multiple GridFS in Mongo? The reason why I am asking is because I am working on with Mongo has both video and image uploads. The problem is I want them to be separate collections but I am using

```
$db ->gridFS();
```

which uses the same collection. So how can I separate the two types and stil use gridFS?

Also for the images, an image file has multiple versions of the image associated with one ID. Can this be done in GridFS? `grid->StoreFile` seems to only store one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To use multiple collections for gridfs, use this [method](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getgridfs.php) with your own prefix

  `$collection = $db->getGridFS($prefix);`
- To save file with multiple versions, I would recommend storing file with generated filename and store image id and version in file metadata instead.